# Use Custom Field to Exclude a Particular Post ID on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have multiple custom post types. On a particular custom post type (a), I am looking to pull in another type of post (b). But I have a custom field on (a) which is the ID of one of the (b) posts which needs to be excluded.

This custom field on (a) changes for each post so cannot be hard coded.

So far I have this:

```
<?php
        unset($args);
        $exclude = the_field( "exclude_tipster_id" );
        $args = array('exclude' => $exclude, 'post_type' => 'oneoff', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'order' => 'rand');
        $lastposts = get_posts($args);
        ?>
            <?php foreach ($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
```

But it's not doing anything. I'm probably doing something stupid. Not much of a coder as you can tell so I'm using Google and the tiny bit of common sense I have.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `$exclude = the_field( "exclude_tipster_id" );` you should be using `get_field()` instead of `the_field()`.

When you use `the_field()` the value will be echoed to the screen, when you use `get_field()` it will assigned to $exclude.

For more information see the documentation here:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/